# what does wrapping a jQuery object in $( ) do?

Tags: jquery, widget

I'm going over the jquery widget here: http://blog.davidpadbury.com/2010/10/11/bdd-testing-of-jquery-plugins-using-jasmine/

The plugin is called like so:

```
$('#list').list({'input':$('#new-value')})
```

So '#new-value' is an input text field.  By wrapping `$()` around '#new-value' it is a jQuery selection.

Inside the widget _create method there is this line:

```
this.input = $( this.options.input )
```

`this.options.input` should be `$('#new-value')`.  It's already a jQuery object right?  Why are they wrapping it within another `$( )`?  What does that do?  Can I leave it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably implemented, so the selector could be given instead of object as the `input` option.

Passing jQuery object into jQuery function changes nothing - the same object is returned. Well, maybe not the same object, but the documentation says about `jQuery` function:

> It will also accept another jQuery object, effectively returning `$(other.get())`.

so it will retrieve DOM objects from jQuery object and pass them again to jQuery function, returning the result.

Comment: That's it. Just call your plugin with '#new-value' instead of $('#new-value'). Better than messing with the code of the plugin ;)

Comment: not the same object, it's a new jQuery object with same contents though

Comment: @Esailija: I have just updated my answer to say this is not identical, before your comment appeared, but thanks for pointing it. You are totally correct.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  This plugin doesn't really do much it's just an example for education purposes regarding jasmine, but even the source code had several lines of code that were unfamiliar to me so I wanted to dissect every line that I didn't understand.